# How can I change the language of Trailhead?

Tags: trailhead, language

I am new.
Trailhead has detected that I am in Spain and it shows me the information in Spanish, but there are a lot of keywords that I prefer to learn in English. How can I change the language of Trailhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current trailhead UI, the language selection picklist is aaaaaallll the way at the bottom of the page on the right-hand side.
[image]

Comment: I was trying to configue my profile and chage de "es" in the url : D 
it was to much easy
thanks.